# jquery one submit to stay on page another to redirect

Tags: jquery, post, dynamic

I have a form which needs to keep updating the input elements in a textarea. I am able to capture the POST data and to update the textarea. The next thins I need to do is capture this while staying on the same page. So I have created 2 submit buttons. I want one of them to submit and stay on the same page so I can capture the POST data and I want another to submit and redirect.
Does anyone know of any solution for this?

Comment: The first one needs to use AJAX. The second one can just submit the form normally, and the server script can return a redirect.

Comment: If you don't want redirect on submit just [prevent default](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp) and use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to perform the request

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing this: $(stay_on_page).click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); $.post('my_php_page.php', $('$my_form_name').serialize()); return false;})      This doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Jquery format to prevent a form from submitting:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(){
  // do anything else you want with the form
  // (for example send an ajax request)

  if (some_condition) { // eg. if a certain button was clicked
    return false; // prevents the normal form submission
  } else {
    // implicit return or returning TRUE allows the normal form submission
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Topher. But i want the form to submit and get the POST request details and stay on the same page